# Jquery Drag and drop to Update MySql DB in Laravel App

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, laravel

I have 5 tables with data.

I can drag and drop rows and reassign their positions. I am grabbing the ID of the DB record they belong to.

I want to be able to update it from table one to table 2 on the database. I was told not to use AJAX because that handles updating records in the front end and it could be dangerous. I dont know what route to go for or even how to manage it.

I am using Laravel 5.3

Comment: Nothing wrong in using ajax request, just make sure that the request type when updating records is post and also include the csrf token.

Comment: Gotcha, well, in this case it would be an update, im just worried about a malicious user being able to intercept and edit the request.

Comment: Just add an auth middleware to your routes and you'll be safe.